# Does Solaris 10 sendmail support SMTP AUTH

Tags: authentication, sendmail, sasl

Can anyone tell me if Solaris 10 now comes with a sendmail binary that supports SMTP AUTH ?
Search brings up many old post on how to complie SASL and Sendmail , but I'd rather use a built in, supported version if there is now one availble.

## Edit

After looking at this , it seems it is not enabled.
Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Sendmail on my Solaris 10 9/10 box is 8.14.4+Sun.

It has also been linked with SASL:

```
$ ldd /usr/sbin/sendmail|grep sasl
        libsasl.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libsasl.so.1
```

In the stock `sendmail.cf`:

```
# SMTP AUTH flags
#O AuthOptions
```

<strike>So yes, it looks like it is supported but you'll need to enable it in the configuration.</strike>

UPDATE

As @AndyM points out in the comments, it looks like this is incorrect and in fact AUTH support is not compiled in to the native Solaris sendmail.

Comment: Ok thanks , I need to go and check its 9/10 thats installed ... fingers crossed :-)

Comment: The version i have installed is 8.14.4+Sun , when I run a sendmail -bt -d0.10 < /dev/null. It does not show the SASL compiled with option , but the ldd does show the lib is linked , I'm confused ?!?!. The reason I ask is I'm getting "Waring Option AuthMechanisms require SASL support (-DSASL) when I run send mail with config that specifies AUTH in the options. I think its been somewho built but not enabled in the binary